# using Apache POI with Android

Tags: android, apache-poi

I have a tried and tested code to get information from an Excel file. It works wonders in java. However, when I try to use it in Android, I get this:

```
11-30 13:26:24.339: I/dalvikvm(9762): Could not find method org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5, referenced from method org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture
```

So, when I try to read a row, it always returns null.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure you included all the dependencies of Apache POI, along with the POI jar? Only it looks like you missed the Commons Codec dependency...

Comment: I was missing the Commons library. It works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer... Apache POI has a small number of [dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), which are fully listed on the [Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on the website. You need to include the dependencies of whichever POI modules you're using. In your case, the exception you got indicated that the Commons Codec library was missing, adding that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this problem, you can download Commons Codec library (or Jar file) from "http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonscodec18jar.htm" or "http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi" link.. and then copy that jar file in "libs" folder of project. Run Your project, It's Done..